# Как узнать сколько секунд длиться музыка через pyglet(или другое) в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я воспроизвожу музыку в python3.6.1 через pyglet.

```
import pyglet
pyglet.lib.load_library('avbin')
pyglet.have_avbin=True
song = pyglet.media.load('music.mp3')
song.seek(67)
song.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Только мне не понятно как узнавать кол-во секунд в музыке(песня, гудок и т. п.).

Как узнать кол-во секунд?

Зарание спасибо.

Comment: `song.duration` ?

Comment: для тех кто pyglet не использует, получить продолжительность медиа можно c помощью  `hachoir3` пакета (чистый Питон). [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17190482/4279).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `pyglet.media.Source` есть свойство [duration](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/media/pyglet.media.Source.html#pyglet.media.Source.duration)

> Длительность источника в секундах или None, если невозможно определить длительность источника

У Вас это `song.duration`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но у меня еще один вопрос.  Как узнать громкость музыки(не колонок). Зарание спасибо.

Comment: Ещё один вопрос нужно задавать по кнопке "Задать вопрос"